# Remove unwanted Symbol from Pardot Landing Page using Wordpress Page Code

Tags: wordpress, symbols, euro, pardot

Trying to remove Euro symbol from button on Pardot landing page (see link below), code for header came from our Wordpress page and using Pardot to host the landing page. Below is the section of code referencing this area.

This does have `<meta charset="utf-8">` at the top as well, may not be relevent but everything I am reading about unwanted symbols that has been referenced.

[image: Image of button that needs Euro symbol removed.]

```
    <a class="header-btn-wrapper" href="COMPANY LINK">
        <p>Request Info</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Please let me know if there is something I can add or switch to not show the Euro symbol anymore. Thank you.